# Unable to return a value from a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a small piece of code to understand how to return values that can be used in other sections of the code. In the following i only want to return the variable z, or the value snooze. But it does not work. Please can someone help me to understand why this will not work?

```
import time

def sleepy(reps, snooze):
    t = []
    for x in range(reps):
        x = time.time()
        time.sleep(snooze)
        y = time.time()

        z = y - x
        t.append(z)
        print 'difference = ', z*1000

    print 'total:', (sum(t)/reps) * 1000
    return z

sleepy(10, 0.001)

print z # does not like this.
```

If I print snooze it also grumbles. Why is that?

Comment: @IcyFlame: Do **not** change code in questions! The whole problem is that `z` is returned but not stored in a variable, don't go around adding that variable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but i feel that since `z` is inside the scope of the `for` loop, it will not be visible to return it

Comment: @silent_warrior: No, Python only creates a new scope for modules and functions (with list, dict and set comprehensions, as well as generator expressions and lambdas, being specialised forms of functions). Variables assigned to in a loop are visible in the rest of that scope.

Comment: @AlexVogel: The same remark to IcyFlame above applies to you too as reviewer. The edit you improved *changed the question* by fixing the problem the OP had a question about. **Do not change code in questions**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sir, I am very sorry. I will take care to not change the code in questions.

Answer (score 8):

`z` is a local variable in your `sleepy()` function; it is not visible outside of that function.

Your function does return the value of `z`; assign it:

```
slept = sleepy(10, 0.001)
print slept
```

I used a different name here to illustrate that `slept` is a different variable.

Comment: _Your function does return the value of z_ do you mean that although z is getting passed, it will not have the intended value (y-x)?

Comment: @silent_warrior: What makes you think that?

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to print `z` or `snooze` because they have a scope that is limited to the definition of the function. When you do: `sleepy(10,0.001)` then the value 10 is assigned to `reps` and the value 0.001 is assigned to `snooze`.

And then the things that you want are done with these variables. In the meantime a new variable called `z` is created with the scope inside the definition of the function. And then this value is returned. And as soon as the last statement has been executed then all the variables that are created inside the definition are deleted.

So you must do:

```
a = sleepy(10,0.001)

print a
```

This will print the value of `a` which is the value that you returned from inside the function.

Also you can print z if you declare it as global, that is:

```
import time

def sleepy(reps, snooze):
    t = []
    for x in range(reps):
        x = time.time()
        time.sleep(snooze)
        y = time.time()

        global z  ##notice this line has been changed.

        z = y - x
        t.append(z)
        print 'difference = ', z*1000

    print 'total:', (sum(t)/reps) * 1000
```

Now the value to be returned is in `z` and you can print it as so:

```
sleepy(10,0.001)

print z
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return something from a function you are calling, the syntax is as follows:

```
p = sleepy(10,0.001)
print p
```

Answer (score 1):

`z` and `snooze` are local variables to the function.

You need to assign the result of the function to a variable to have it available after the function call.

Answer (score 1):

z is a local variable.when you `return z` it not actually returns variable `z` instead its 
returns the value which is present in `z` so u need to store it in another variable and print that variable  
or you can just use

```
print sleepy(10, 0.001)
```